# Modifiable Collection Rally WSAPI

Tags: rally

I have a simple question about Rally WSAPI doc. Just to confirm, the `Modifiable Collection` field in the documentation informs if this collection can be updated or not, is that correct?

Comment: @KyleMorse So does it mean I can only change roles of team members for a project by logging into Rally and not by using a script to do it? Because the abstract type "UserPermissions" is not modifiable .

Comment: UserPermissions is readonly but you can instead create/update/delete ProjectPermission and WorkspacePermission objects for that user.

Comment: @KyleMorse yes but can I change the roles ("Editor" ,"Viewer" ..) using a script?

Comment: @KyleMorse No that's a question, can I change roles using a script?

Comment: Yes, you can do this.

Comment: @KyleMorse Can you briefly explain the steps to be followed? I can then write the code. Thanks

Comment: According to the docs the Role field on UserPermission is actually read-only, so you'll have to delete any permissions that are incorrect and just create new instances of WorkspacePermission or ProjectPermission with the correct role.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Using json dynamic object we can do it as below:

```
    DynamicJsonObject newProjectPermission = new DynamicJsonObject();

    newProjectPermission["User"] = myUser;
    newProjectPermission["Project"] = myProject;
    newProjectPermission["Role"] = "Editor";
```